# Are doses in inputevents_mv correct?

Tags: mimic-iii

Just trying to get some drug doses out from mimic-iii but having a little trouble making sense of the data.

I'm trying to find the doses of morphine sulphate given to patients in their first day but the "amount" column seems to be out by a factor of 1000.

Looking at inputevents_mv.row_id being 9902. It states that Morphine Sulphate was given as an infusion at 10mg/hr for 6 hours and 13 minutes. I expected the amount to be 62.167mg yet the "amount" column reports that as 0.0621670036 with a unit of measurement (amountuom) being "mg".

The same occurs for all patients - some of them have been given 0.002 of a mg of morphine which again isn't really an actual dose. It's far too homeopathic for adults.

Is it safe to presume that all morphine doses are out by 1000? What about other drugs?

Best Wishes,

-Ahmed :)

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue in MIMIC-III v1.3 which has been corrected in v1.4. All doses should now be in the correct unit (before they were all in grams, erroneously).

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm based on morphine doses that either the unit of measurement is out (mg instead of g) or the amount is out by a factor of 1000...

-Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

it is best to review manually any outliers to be honest....